# Javafx : test with a layout manager?

Tags: layout, javafx, layout-manager, shapes

I'm learning javafx and I made few try with the vbox layout manager. The code seems to be ok but I wanna check if I really understood how it works.

Here is the code :

```
public class TestShape2 extends Application {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      launch(args);
  }

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
      Group root = new Group();
      Label topLabel = new Label("Top...");
      Label topLabel2 = new Label("Top 2...");
      Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();

      rect.setFill(Color.AQUA);
      Label bottomLabel = new Label("Bottom...");

      VBox vBox = new VBox();
      rect.widthProperty().bind(vBox.widthProperty());
      rect.heightProperty().bind(vBox.heightProperty());

      vBox.getChildren().addAll(topLabel, topLabel2, rect, bottomLabel);
      /*
       * Code 1
       */
      root.getChildren().add(vBox);
      Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 300, Color.BLANCHEDALMOND);

      /*
       * Code 2
       */
      // Scene scene = new Scene (vBox, 300, 300, Color.BLANCHEDALMOND);

      primaryStage.setScene(scene);
      primaryStage.show();

  }

}
```

In the "code 1" : does the width and height of the vBox are those of the elements contained in the root ass the root group is the parent of the vbox ? And so, the vBox don't fill the whole space ?
In the "code 2" : as I don't use some root group, the vbox dimensions will be the ones of the scene as the scene is the parent of the vbox ? 
Does my understanding is correct ?

If that's correct, my question is : what would be the code to have a "top label", a "bottom label" and a rectangle that would fill all the free space ? In the code 2, I never see the bottom label" as it seems the rectangle height is the height of the scene so, I suppose the bottom label is out of the scene. But how to solve that ?

Thank you all for your help in understanding javafx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
rect.heightProperty().bind(vBox.heightProperty());
```

is a thing you should not do. It resizes the `Rectangle` according to the size of its parent. However there the height of the parent depends on the size of its children. This circular dependency leads to the `VBox`'s behavior no longer being well defined...

> In the "code 1" : does the width and height of the vBox are those of the elements contained in the root ass the root group is the parent of the vbox ?

The size of a `Group`'s children is the prefered size. Combined with the issue described above you get a layout that does not fill the whole width/height available.

> In the "code 2" : as I don't use some root group, the vbox dimensions will be the ones of the scene as the scene is the parent of the vbox ?

Mostly correct except for some imprecise formulation: The `Scene` is not the `parent` of any `Node`. The `VBox` is the root of the `Scene` and the `Scene` contains the `VBox`.

> In the code 2, I never see the bottom label" as it seems the rectangle height is the height of the scene so, I suppose the bottom label is out of the scene.

That is correct.

`Rectangle` is not a resizable so it doesn't work well with a `VBox` parent to achieve the desired behavior. You can use ´Region´ instead however, which is resizable. Filling can be done using the `Region`'s background and stroke could replaced by a border, if needed.

Setting `vgrow` to `Priority.ALWAYS` tells the `VBox` to always resize the `Region` instead of other children and setting `fillWidth` to `true` tells the `VBox` to change the children's size to it's own width:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    Label topLabel = new Label("Top...");
    Label topLabel2 = new Label("Top 2...");

    Region rect = new Region();
    rect.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.AQUA, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));

    Label bottomLabel = new Label("Bottom...");

    VBox vBox = new VBox();
    vBox.setFillWidth(true);

    VBox.setVgrow(rect, Priority.ALWAYS);

    vBox.getChildren().addAll(topLabel, topLabel2, rect, bottomLabel);

    Scene scene = new Scene (vBox, 300, 300, Color.BLANCHEDALMOND);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```